# Jquery Autocomplete when response data in the form of Map<Long, String>

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, autocomplete

I am trying to create JQuery AutoComplete,where source object  in form of Map `<Long,String>`

I received the data in this format

```
{"30":"rt4t@wqd.com","31":"fgwerfewr@frffe.com","28":"ankit4004@mailinator.com","29":"fjhf@fjhfhj.com","26":"jobseeker2@mailinator.com","27":"jobseeker3@mailinator.com","24":"witty@mailinator.com","25":"jobseeker1@mailinator.com","22":"hello@mailinator.com","23":"jobseeker@mailinator.com","21":"mds@mailinator.com","18":"rajpal.chauhan315@gmail.com","16":"raj5@gmail.com","17":"raj6@gmail.com","15":"raj4@gmail.com","14":"raj3@gmail.com","13":"raj2@gmail.com","12":"raj1@gmail.com","11":"raj@gmail.com","10":"xyz@gmail.com","9":"hello@gmail.com","8":"shivit@gmail.com","7":"raj@mailinator.com","6":"test123@mailinator.com","5":"xyz2@mailinator.com","4":"xyz1@mailinator.com","3":"xyz@mailinator.com","2":"ashu8006kumar@gmail.com","1":"sadmin@emh.com"}}...........
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage response data in this way:

```js
var map = {"30":"rt4t@wqd.com","31":"fgwerfewr@frffe.com","28":"ankit4004@mailinator.com","29":"fjhf@fjhfhj.com","26":"jobseeker2@mailinator.com","27":"jobseeker3@mailinator.com","24":"witty@mailinator.com","25":"jobseeker1@mailinator.com","22":"hello@mailinator.com","23":"jobseeker@mailinator.com","21":"mds@mailinator.com","18":"rajpal.chauhan315@gmail.com","16":"raj5@gmail.com","17":"raj6@gmail.com","15":"raj4@gmail.com","14":"raj3@gmail.com","13":"raj2@gmail.com","12":"raj1@gmail.com","11":"raj@gmail.com","10":"xyz@gmail.com","9":"hello@gmail.com","8":"shivit@gmail.com","7":"raj@mailinator.com","6":"test123@mailinator.com","5":"xyz2@mailinator.com","4":"xyz1@mailinator.com","3":"xyz@mailinator.com","2":"ashu8006kumar@gmail.com","1":"sadmin@emh.com"};

var source = $.map(map, function( value, key ){
       return {         value: key, label: value,}
      });
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: source,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#tags" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#tags" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


Autocomplete : <br>
<input id="tags">
```